# How does Ether-Pudding/Truffle handle Metamask and Mist browser?

Tags: mist, dapp-development, contract-deployment, metamask

Is there anything different with how the accounts are managed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing special, Truffle simply defaults to the global web3 object in the way recommended by MetaMask, and retrieves the accounts from that object:

https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check

Comment: Ok great that has all the info I need.

Comment: If you mark the answer as "the solution", I get magical internet points.

Comment: Ahaha it's a magical currency